# Python or SQL: Populating an excel form (multiple times and saving outputs) from another table

Tags: python, sql, excel

**Problem:** Customer has requested we fill out a form (excel) for each item we provide them. Due to us providing them a large amount of parts, I would like to figure out a way to automate it as much as possible.

**Idea:** Create a table ('Data') with each part number and relevant information in the columns. Use Python to read 'Data' table, open blank customer form, populate blank customer form, and then save customer form.

**Questions:**

- Can SQL accomplish this task as well? In relation to this task, I've only really created flat table outputs with SQL. Not really sure how this would work.
- Recommended Python packages / documentation?
- Similar example with code available? Just helps me learn being able to walk through something.
- Any other ideas? Maybe I am tackling this issue the wrong way.

I am just unsure of my best path of action.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple table on your SQL system (PostgreSQL, MySQL), so you can add modify simply your items.

Then you can export your table in excel format as the customer wants with:

```
Copy (Select * From foo) To '/tmp/test.csv' With CSV DELIMITER ',';
```

You can also do it with python, but i think it's more complicated to update item with python, with a SQL system you could create and HTML/PHP front-end page making it more customizable.